# Better parameter error handling; and better parameter parsing/handling?

Tags: parsing, powershell, parameters, arguments, powershell-2.0

I have a script like this:

```
param(
  [Alias('a')]
  [string]$aval,
  [Alias('b')]
  [switch]$bval,
  [Alias('c')]
  [string]$cval
)

if($aval.length -gt 1)
{
  Do-Something
}
elseif($bval)
{
  Do-Something-Else
}
elseif($cval.length -gt 1)
{
  Do-Another-Thing
}
else
{
  Do-This
}
```

If someone calls my script like so, an ugly error is displayed saying it is missing an argument for parameter 'aval/bval/cval':

```
PS C:\> .\MyScript.ps1 -a
C:\MyScript.ps1 : Missing an argument for parameter 'aval'. Specify a
parameter of type 'System.String' and try again.
At line:1 char:18
+ .\MyScript.ps1 -n <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [MyScript.ps1],    ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument,MyScript.ps1
```

Is there any way to make a cleaner, possibly one line, error appear instead? Also, is there a better way to handle parameters then a list of elseif statements (my actual script has ~10 parameters)?

The script sometimes passes an argument with a parameter as well:

```
EX:
PS C:\> .\MyScript.ps1 -b ServerName
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that you can look at here. First, if the parameter will never have an associated value and you just want to know if the script was called with the parameter or not, then use a [switch] parameter instead of a string.

Here is a very simple example of using a switch parameter:

```
param(
        [switch]$a
     )

if($a){
    'Switch was present'
}else{
    'No switch present'
}
```

Save that as a script and run it with and without the -a parameter.

If you will sometimes have the parameter present with some value being passed in but other times without the value, then give the parameter a default value when you define it:

```
[Alias('a')]
[string]$aval = '',
```

Then in your logic if something was passed in, the length of the string will be gt 1.

As for the if-then structure that you have, there are a plethora of options for handling this sort of logic. with the little bit of information that you have shared, I suspect that using switch structure will be the best plan:

```
Get-Help about_Switch
```

Comment: I still receive the "missing an argument for parameter" error when setting a default value. If I pass the argument like this I the error occurs " .\MyScript.ps1 -a ".

As for the switch, I'm not sure if I'll be able to use that. I'll read through the documentation, but I'm not looking for the different arguments passed in with a parameter (ex: .\MyScript.ps1 -a ServerName), I'm looking for the existence of a parameter being passed (where each parameter is a variable; ex: $a). Then based on what parameter is passed, do something different.

Comment: It is a little confusing. As I said, if all you care about is the presence or absence of the parameter, use a switch type parameter. I edited my answer to provide a very simple example.